# Are there other religions in the "Priest" universe?

Tags: priest-2011, priest-1998

I've recently rewatched the 2011 film *Priest* of Scott Stewart with Paul Bettany, Karl Urban and Maggie Q. As the story goes, the Priests have saved humanity from vampires. While watching, I wondered if there are other religions, maybe in other regions of the world, than Christianity / Catholicism.

So, is there any reference in the film (I've missed) or the comic it apparently is loosely based on from Min-Woo Hyung concerning other religions in this universe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The manhwa is from the point of view of a Catholic priest, spanning the Crusades to the near future, so there's no particular reason why other religions would appear. Since God explicitly exists in that universe, and the main plot revolves around actual fallen angels, there might simply not be any other religions any more because in that setting, the monotheists are right.

The film, supposedly set 150 years after the end of the comic (but is really an In Name Only sequel), states in its opening narration that humans and vampires were at war for most of recorded history, so possibly over thousands of years. The religion in the film might have some Christian/Catholic trappings, but is not explicitly called as such, and in any case religious faith is shown to have no actual power against the vampires; the vampires were fought by purely physical means. The Church is merely your bog-standard dystopian government. What they actually believe in isn't clearly shown; other than crosses and holy books, there's nothing telling the viewer anything about them, other than monotheist (due to reference to "God") and if they didn't show those, there's be no reason to think it was Christianity at all.

Because most people, even if they belong to other religions or aren't religious at all, recognize many of the trappings of Roman Catholicism (crosses, confession, bibles, rosaries, traditional nun uniforms, the hierarchy, the terminology), using that Catholic symbolism is a cheap and easily recognizable way of saying "religion" without actually having to explain anything, which is why it's used a lot in manga and anime and so common on film. If you wanted to show a character has belief in their faith without explicitly going on at length about it such as having them attend a religious service, it's easier to show someone fingering their rosary beads or going to confession than it would be if your fiction's religious practices were more based on Protestant or Mormon beliefs, or even had nothing to do with Christianity at all.

Comment: What made me think of Chridtianity are mostly the croses, Catholizism is the rosary and confession